# $S=T\circ T + T+\mathrm{Id}_V$ and there is a $T$-invariant subspace $U\subseteq V$ with $ \dim (U) = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V < \infty$. Let $T, S:V\rightarrow V$ be linear operators, $S=T\circ T + T+\mathrm{Id}_V$ and $\dim\mathrm{Im}(S) < \dim (V)$. How to prove that there exists a $T$-invariant subspace, $U \subseteq V$, such that $\dim(U) = 2$ ?

Comment: do you mean perhaps that $\dim (U) \geq 2$?

Comment: well, not every two-dimensional subspace would be invariant but I see what you mean

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Actually, I don't any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can guarantee such an invariant subspace with $\dim(U) \leq 2$.

Since $\dim \operatorname{Im}(S) < \dim (V)$, we know that $\dim \ker (S) > 0$.  That is, there exists a non-zero vector $x \in V$ such that
$$
Sx = T^2x + Tx + x = 0
$$
Now, let $U$ denote the span of the vectors $x,Tx$.  We see that $U$ is an invariant subspace of $T$ since $T(x) \in U$ and $T(Tx) = -Tx - x \in U$.  $U$ is at most $2$ dimensional since it is spanned by two vectors, and it is non-zero since $x \neq 0$.

It is not necessarily possible to attain $\dim(U) = 2$.  For instance: consider the matrix
$$
T = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 2&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0& \lambda}
$$
as a transformation $\Bbb Q^3 \to \Bbb Q^3$ over $\Bbb Q[\lambda]$, where $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1 = 0$.  Then $T$ satisfies the conditions of the problem, but the only invariant subspace with dimension at most $2$ is the span of $(0,0,0,1)$.

Comment: It is surprisingly tough to think of a field in which $x^2 + x + 1$ has a root but in which there exists an irreducible cubic polynomial.   I probably could have done something similar with $\Bbb F_3$, come to think of it.